# vim doesnt load after removing rvm (libruby.so.1.8: cannot open shared object file)

Tags: ruby, linux, vim, ubuntu, rvm

I've removed recently rvm and reinstalled it, that worked fine.
But now, when I'm trying to start vim or gvim, I'm getting the following error message:

> vim: error while loading shared libraries: libruby.so.1.8: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory"

Googling wasn't very helpful for me here.
I'm on Ubuntu 11.10.

Does anyone know this problem or could anyone give me a hint where I should look in detail?

Comment: What's the output of `ldd $(which vim) | grep ruby` ?

Comment: libruby.so.1.8 => not found :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

On my Ubuntu system, `vim` is compiled against Ruby and the linker/loader `ld.so(8)` finds the `libruby1.8` library here:

```
$ ldd `which vim` | grep ruby
libruby1.8.so.1.8 => /usr/lib/libruby1.8.so.1.8 (0x00007f0184795000)

$ dlocate /usr/lib/libruby1.8.so.1.8
libruby1.8: /usr/lib/libruby1.8.so.1.8.7
libruby1.8: /usr/lib/libruby1.8.so.1.8
```

If you install the `libruby1.8` package with `sudo apt-get install libruby1.8`, then the library will be available for your `vim` to use. I do not know why `rvm` would choose to mess with system-supplied Ruby installs but that sounds like a misconfiguration of `rvm` to me.

Another option is that your `vim` was self-compiled against one specific version of Ruby as managed by `rvm`. If this is the case, and you liked that setup, then install whatever version of Ruby you want with `rvm`, rebuild your `vim` with the path to your customized Ruby installation, and re-install `vim`.

(If the preceding paragraph made no sense, I strongly recommend sticking to the distribution-provided `vim` package.)

Comment: Thanks! Vim is working again. I've removed rvm and all ruby/libruby stuff from the ubuntu distribution and then I've completely removed all vim stuff (using "sudo apt-get remove vim-common", not just "sudo apt-get remove vim") and reinstalled it. :-)

Comment: This was a lifesaver!